# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string [Expo42 - React Navigation 4]

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I just updated my project from expo 39 to 42. The project use React Navigation 4.
Before the update everything worked and now I get the annoying error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at App.js:89.
>
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
>
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
>
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
>
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
>
> in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
>
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
>
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
>
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

App.js

```c
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { GlobalColor } from './src/config/helpers';
import { AppContainer } from './src/config/navigation.js';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

function cacheImages(images) {
    return images.map(image => {
        if (typeof image === 'string') {
            return Image.prefetch(image);
        } else {
            return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
        }
    });
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
    return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoadingComplete: false,
        };
    }

    async _loadAssetsAsync() {
        const imageAssets = cacheImages([
            ...
        ]);
        const fontAssets = cacheFonts([{
            ...
        }]);

        await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
    }

    _handleLoadingError = error => {
        // do something
    };

    _handleFinishLoading = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
    };

    componentDidMount() {}

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
            return (
                <AppLoading
                    startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
                    onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
                    onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <AppContainer />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: GlobalColor.white,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Navigation.js

```c
import { ScreenWidth, EaseOutQuint } from '../config/helpers';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// Main Screens
import ...

// Account Screens
import ...

...
...

const AppStack = createSwitchNavigator({
    SplashView : SplashView,
    UserLoggedOut : OriginStack,
    UserLoggedIn: MainStack,
},{
    headerMode: 'none',
});

export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);
```

package.json

```c
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
    "expo": "^42.0.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~10.1.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-page-control": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AppLoading didn't update to the latest version so had to run

```c
expo install expo-app-loading
```

and then change the import

```c
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the following dependencies

```
npm i expo-asset
npm i expo-font
```

Comment: these were surely missing in the package.json, but even after restarting cleaning cache I still get the error

Comment: "Check your code at App.js:89" what line is this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined.

This means that a component is being referenced but doesn't exist (henced the `undefined`, when React tries to validate the type).

The error message also points to `line 89` of `App.js`. See what code is there and trace it from there.

Check that whatever component referenced there is exported/imported properly. If the component in turn contains other imported components, check that these are too.

Most of the time, this is due to an incorrect export/import, but there a few other reasons that could also cause this error:

- Conflict with a file of the same name as the component, but different file extension.

  In that case, specify the extension in the import statement.
- Improperly passing a component as properties.

  In that case, check that you're passing the component with the correct syntax, and inspect the component beforehand to check that it's the correct type.

Comment: Yes! you prompt me to think :P
It was AppLoading - it didn't update to the latest.
So all I had to do was install it and import it the new way

`import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';`